# Build failed because of webpack errors (Next build failing)

Tags: next.js

```
✓ Linting and checking validity of types    
Failed to compile.

HookWebpackError: /Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/static/css/1551a2845839407e.css:1643:189: Unknown word
    at makeWebpackError (/Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:28:311209)
    at /Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:28:106058
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:13:28867), <anonymous>:34:1)
-- inner error --
CssSyntaxError: /Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/static/css/1551a2845839407e.css:1643:189: Unknown word
    at Input.error (/Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/postcss/lib/input.js:106:16)
    at ScssParser.unknownWord (/Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/postcss/lib/parser.js:594:22)
    at ScssParser.other (/Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/postcss/lib/parser.js:436:12)
    at ScssParser.parse (/Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/postcss/lib/parser.js:471:16)
    at scssParse (/Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-scss/scss-syntax.js:1:322)
    at new LazyResult (/Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:133:16)
    at Processor.process (/Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/postcss/lib/processor.js:53:14)
    at CssMinimizerPlugin.optimizeAsset (/Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/plugins/css-minimizer-plugin.js:48:12)
    at /Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/plugins/css-minimizer-plugin.js:80:55
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:105:20)
caused by plugins in Compilation.hooks.processAssets
CssSyntaxError: /Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/static/css/1551a2845839407e.css:1643:189: Unknown word
    at Input.error (/Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/postcss/lib/input.js:106:16)
    at ScssParser.unknownWord (/Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/postcss/lib/parser.js:594:22)
    at ScssParser.other (/Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/postcss/lib/parser.js:436:12)
    at ScssParser.parse (/Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/postcss/lib/parser.js:471:16)
    at scssParse (/Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-scss/scss-syntax.js:1:322)
    at new LazyResult (/Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:133:16)
    at Processor.process (/Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/postcss/lib/processor.js:53:14)
    at CssMinimizerPlugin.optimizeAsset (/Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/plugins/css-minimizer-plugin.js:48:12)
    at /Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/plugins/css-minimizer-plugin.js:80:55
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/Users/arsi/Documents/projects/next-first-project/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:105:20)
```

I want to deploy my project but every time I run build it fails. I've tried changing settings in package json and next configs but it didn't work.

Comment: Based on the error, it looks like something in your css is wonky.